# How to stop toggling of navigation drawer when it is open

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to stop back button to close the navigation drawer. Please if there will be any solution for this then give me answer with example if you want.

My code is here in which i have used expandable list view in which first there will be no child but when he click on any item then i just change the array of setAdapter and give them children. So Can you please tell what change i do to implement like myntra left menu.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import com.teamtreehouse.oslist.Adapter.ExpandableListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private String mActivityTitle;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    List<String> listDataHeader1;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild1;
    public static boolean isBack = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        expListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        expListView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        expListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
        prepareListData();
        prepareListData1();

        setupDrawer();
        addDrawerItems();


        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        Log.d("tag", "here i am in addDrawerItems");

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isBack = false;


                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader1, listDataChild1);

                // setting list adapter
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                Log.d("tag", "here i am in setOngroupclick listitener");

                return true;
            }
        });





    }

    private void setupDrawer() {

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {

        Log.d("tag","the keydown button");
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
                && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            // Take care of calling this method on earlier versions of
            // the platform where it doesn't exist.
            onBackPressed();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            Log.d("tag","the back button is pressed");
            return;
        } else {
            Log.d("tag","the back button is pressed2");
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return  true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshan");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfathe");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, t");
        top250.add("The Dark ");
        top250.add("12 Angry");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown U");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolveri");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacu");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }

    private void prepareListData1() {
        listDataHeader1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild1 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader1.add("Second List");
        listDataHeader1.add("New List");
        listDataHeader1.add("Old List");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshan");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfathe");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, t");
        top250.add("The Dark ");
        top250.add("12 Angry");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable");


        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacu");


        listDataChild1.put(listDataHeader1.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild1.put(listDataHeader1.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild1.put(listDataHeader1.get(2), comingSoon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do any of the logs get printed when you press the back button? Can you remove the `onKeyDown` method and try again? What's your app's minSdkVersion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can override `onBackPressed()` in your Activity, checking if the drawer is open, and swallowing the event if so.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        return;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In a standard application, it is normal behaviour to close the drawer using the back button; please only apply this if it's *necessary* for your case.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but this method does'nt call on clicking of back button. Actually I want this because i want to change the items of navigation drawer by clicking of any item inside it. But on clicking of back button the previous item get loaded which must not close the drawer that's why i want this. Actually I want to make menu like myntra app

Comment: Is there any method to stop the drawer to get closed.

Comment: I just downloaded the myntra app and the back button does indeed close the navigation drawer if it is open. Perhaps the device you're testing on is non-standard.

Comment: In Myntra app just click on (Men) item on left menu then you will go to its sub category and then click back button.

Comment: Ah ok, see what you mean. The `onBackPressed()` is a method you override from the Activity class - it needs to be defined in your Activity, was it?

Comment: I have pasted my code you can see it . thanks for your response

Comment: Is there any other way to implement this